# XCode: Cocoapods: How to avoid X.0.0 versions?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile

Regarding the Podfile file of an iOS project in Xcode:

We prefer to not bring down X.0.0 libs. So 5.0.1 is good, 5.1.0 is good, 5.1.1 is definitely good, but not 5.0.0

I cannot see syntax that supports this rule in [this doc](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod). Anyone knows? Thank you!